# ModelBuilder.Ignore and [NotMapped] for Model used in Stored Procedure Call

Tags: c#, entity-framework, stored-procedures, asp.net-core

Utilizing code first, I created a stored procedure which I call with

```
_context.MySQLModel.FromSql
```

I created the MySQLModel just for the stored procedure, I don't want to create a table in the database with that name.

So in the model I specified [NotMapped]:

```
public class MySQLModel
{
    [Key]
    public int IdMySQLModel { get; set; }
    public string Something { get; set; }
    public string SomethingTwo { get; set; }
}
```

In ApplicationDbContext I added

```
public DbSet<MySQLModel> MySQLModel { get; set; }
```

and under

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
```

included

```
builder.Ignore<MySQLModel>();
```

On execution, it fails with the following message:

> System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot create a DbSet for 'MySQLModel' because this type is not included in the model for the context.

So I go ahead and comment out

```
//builder.Ignore<MySQLModel>();
```

Run again, runs perfectly. I go ahead and modify or create a new model, do a "Add-Migration" and code to generate the table is on the migration.

Is there a way to get it so it doesn't create code for a new table and still execute the stored procedure?

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [`DbQuery<>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/query-types) (available in `EF Core 2.1`) instead of `DbSet<>`:

```
public DbQuery<MySQLModel> MySQLModel { get; set; }
```

Then there is no need to call `builder.Ignore<MySQLModel>();` and use `[NotMapped]`

You can use it in the similar way:

```
var mySQLModels = _context.MySQLModel.FromSql("select * from MySQLModelView");
```